# How to redirect if succes login with Google in Nuxt js

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

here I try to log in using google at nuxt.js, but when I log in with my Google account, the page doesn't move

has anyone experienced the same thing?

I hope someone provides an example of the code. thank you

[image]

this.my code login.vue

```
 async loginGoogle() {
    try {
      let response = await this.$auth.loginWith('google', {})
      console.log(response)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

this my code nuxt.config.js

```
 google: {
    client_id: 'xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have take a look at https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options.html#redirect

It looks different they use `auth` in ther nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
  redirect: {
    login: '/login',
    logout: '/',
    callback: '/login',
    home: '/'
  }
}
```